# Convet Html string to PDF in Dotnet 7 without warnings

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, html-to-pdf

I want to convert an html string into a byte[] pdf and send it as a file for download. But all the libraries I see either have dependency issues or won't work and give errors like "System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform.".

I'm working on Ubuntu
Dotnet version **7.0.102**

Some packages give warning like -

> "Package 'PDFsharp 1.32.3057' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

this stops me from being able to use hot reload feature when using dotnet watch, it asks me to restart the server on every change.

Comment: you are using packages working only on windows

Comment: Can I get the packages that work on Linux as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iTextSharp` library for this.

Please refer to the below code snippet for your reference :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace HTMLToPDFExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your string HTML here
            string html = @"<html><body>
                                <h1>Example HTML to PDF Conversion</h1>
                                <p>This is an example of how to convert an HTML string to a PDF document.</p>
                            </body></html>";
            string pdfFile = "example.pdf";

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
                {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        using (var sr = new StringReader(html))
                        {
                            var htmlContext = new HTMLWorker(doc);
                            htmlContext.Parse(sr);
                        }
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
                File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFile, ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iTextSharp gives >"Package 'PDFsharp 1.32.3057' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project." similar warning and forces me to restart the server after every edit, also its sole dependency Bouncy caslte is deprecated [https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/